# Multi Level Tree in Umbraco Custom Section

Tags: c#, .net, tree, umbraco

I'm currently trying to create a custom tree and I'm running into trouble when trying to render a nodes children. After browsing various articles/posts I'm at this point:

```
public override void Render(ref XmlTree tree)
{
  List<Node> articles = NodeUtil.GetAllNodesOfDocumentType(-1, "Promoter");
  Node article = articles.Where(p => p.CreatorID == UmbracoEnsuredPage.CurrentUser.Id).FirstOrDefault();

  if(promo != null)
  {
      var dNode = XmlTreeNode.Create(this);
      dNode.NodeID = article.Id.ToString();
      dNode.Text = article.Name;
      dNode.Icon = "doc.gif";
      dNode.Action = "javascript:openArticle(" + article.Id + ")";
      dNode.Source = article.Children.Count > 0 ? this.GetTreeServiceUrl("" + article.Id) : "";
      tree.Add(dNode);
  }
}
```

The code above gets the article belonging to the current user (for the sake of testing, each user only has one article at the moment). I then attempt to print out the children of this article but instead of getting the desired output, I get the follwowing:

```
Article Name
- Article Name
  - Article Name
   - Article Name
```

Each time I expand a node, it just seems to render the same node, and goes on and on.

I've seen other ways of using the treeservice, like:

```
TreeService treeService = new TreeService(...);
node.Source = treeService.GetServiceUrl();
```

But I get an error saying there is no GetServiceUrl method that takes 0 arguments. I assume the method above was for earlier versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to work this out. Here is the solution, hope it would help someone.

```
const string PARENT_ID = "10"; // The ID of the node that has child nodes

public override void Render(ref XmlTree tree)
{
  if (this.NodeKey == PARENT_ID) // Rendering the child nodes of the parent folder
  {
    // Render a child node
    XmlTreeNode node = XmlTreeNode.Create(this);
    node.NodeID = "11";
    node.Text = "child";
    node.Icon = "doc.gif";
    node.Action = ...
    tree.Add(node);
  }
  else // Default (Rendering the root)
  {
    // Render the parent folder
    XmlTreeNode node = XmlTreeNode.Create(this);
    node.NodeID = PARENT_ID;
    node.Source = this.GetTreeServiceUrl(node.NodeID);
    node.Text = "parent";
    node.Icon = "folder.gif";
    tree.Add(node);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for this - I didn't realise it called render each time you open a node - so was confused for a long time about why I kept getting nodes repeated all over the place ;)

Answer (score 1):

The output suggests that the node tree you're building is nesting each child node - this is [because the nodeId is being reset to -1 with each pass](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/8520-Custom-Section-Tree-Child-Node).

[This post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/8520-Custom-Section-Tree-Child-Node) on our.umbraco.org describes the same problem, and suggests that you use NodeKey instead of ID to move between nodes.

**

Not necessarily helpful but I would use the [uQuery language extensions](http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=uQuery) that comes with the ucomponents package (and who installs Umbraco without ucomponents?), to simplify the method calls:

For example:

```
List<Node> articles = uQuery.getNodesByType("Promoter");
foreach(Node article in articles)
{
  List<Node> children = article.GetDescendantNodes();
  ... build tree
}
```

Comment: Hi amelvin, thanks for your response. I'm away from my computer at the moment but the information you've given seems very helpful. I will report back when I have tried it out. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hi amelvin, i'm still yet to get round to trying this out, but it seems like its exactly what I did, and has resolved the issue for other users (oon the umbraco forum). Im going to accept this answer for now, and I'll report back if I find that it hasn't worked. Thanks!